# Как записать условие "Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [2894;174882], которые оканчиваются цифрой 8...."

Tags: python

Вот само задание :
Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [2894;174882], которые оканчиваются цифрой 8 и у которых сумма цифр больше 22. Найдите количество таких чисел и такое тринадцатое число по порядку. В ответе запишите два целых числа: сначала количество, затем тринадцатое такое число.

```
for i in range(2894, 174883):
    if (i%8 == 0 and i%22 != 0):
        a.append(i)
print(len(a),(sum(a)))
```

Comment: В чем именно проблема?

Comment: Как записать именно:которые оканчиваются цифрой 8 и у которых сумма цифр больше 22.

Comment: С чем именно тут проблема? "Больше 22" это ``n>22``, "равно 8" это ``m==8``

Comment: for i in range(2894, 174883):
Ну типо как это сюда вставить

Comment: Что куда вставить?

Comment: Ну как мне это условие вставить в компилятор, что бы получился ответ, я знаю как диапозон указать, но не знаю как к нему привязать "которые оканчиваются цифрой 8 и у которых сумма цифр больше 22".

Comment: Ну вычленяй последнюю цифру и считай сумму чисел отдельно. Это задача для второго класса. Кстати, можно сразу брать числа, оканчивающиеся на 8 и уменьшить количество работы.

Comment: у меня эта задача будет на егэ, на нее должно уйти вроде минут 5, зачем что-то вычленять и считать сумму чисел отдельно, я спросил как это записать програмно.

Comment: Как зачем? Чтобы решить задачу. Думаешь, сумма чисел сама по себе посчитается?

Comment: Ну в питоне есть sum, я не знаю как это применить.

Comment: Как число превратить в рассыпуху из цифр понимаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[]

for i in range(2894, 174883):
    if str(i)[-1] == "8" and sum([int(j) for j in str(i)]) > 22:
        a.append(i)

print(len(a), a[12])
```

Comment: спасибо, а то что-то запутался

Comment: Квадратные скобки внутри `sum` можно не писать. Окончание на `8` можно проверить и так: `i % 10 == 8`

Comment: А какая проверка окончания работает быстрее?

Comment: Зависит наверное от многого, я попробовал в `Google Colab`, мой вариант отработал в среднем в 2 раза быстрее.